# не устанавливается ни один плагин gulp

Tags: gulp

Не устанавливает ни один плагин Gulp 
например,

```
npm i gulp-sass --save-dev
```

Пишет про не поддерживаемую платформу:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
>   okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
>   1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
>   })
>
> npm WARN my_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> D:\Gulp\myProject>

Куда рыть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваши плагины **нормально** устанавливаются. Это можно проверить открыв папку `node_modules` и убедившись в наличии папки с именем, совпадающим с именем модуля (в вашем случае `gulp-sass`).

---

**Для справки**

`Warn` - сокращение от `warning` (предупреждение). Очевидно, что "*предупреждение*" не тоже самое, что и "*ошибка*".

Более того, конструкция:

> SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY

дословно переводится как:

> Пропущена НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНАЯ зависимость

Это означает, что волноваться вообще не о чем.

Comment: спасибо, все понятно, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Проверить установленные плагины в проектной папке (где находится `gulpfile.js`) можно командой:
`npm ls --depth=0`. 
Это более удобная форма, чем рыться во всех бесконечных зависимостях npm.